# Multiple Inheritance in Java even if class inherits Object

Tags: java, object, multiple-inheritance

All classes in Java are inherited from Object class by default.

Then how the class inherited can inherit other classes?

Java do not support Multiple inheritance, right?

Comment: Because when you inherit from another class, you don't inherit directly from `Object` anymore. You'll inherit from `Object` **through** your custom class. The class still has only one parent.

Answer (score 4):

Classes inherit from **at least and at most** one class,

Either from Object implicitly (without writing `extends`), or from other class explicitly (as `extends YourParentClass`)

> Excepting Object, which has no superclass, every class has one and only one direct superclass (single inheritance). In the absence of any other explicit superclass, every class is implicitly a subclass of Object

Because each class inherit from Object or from class inherit from Object, each class still inherit from Object, for example `toString()` method

If your custom class inherit from different class, still at the end of the hierarchy, the parent class will be Object, notice that classes [hierarchy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) isn't multiple inheritance:

> The Object class, defined in the java.lang package, defines and implements behavior common to all classes—including the ones that you write. In the Java platform, **many classes derive directly from Object, other classes derive from some of those classes, and so on, forming a hierarchy of classes**
>
> **At the top of the hierarchy, Object** is the most general of all classes. Classes near the bottom of the hierarchy provide more specialized behavior.

Comment: I think op is treating the inheritance chain as multiple inheritance, therefore the confusion.

Comment: @Spidey updated to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1):

As you already correctly stated, all classes in Java are inherited from Object class by default. That means that any class that does NOT have an `extends` clause defined, implicitly has written `extends Object`. Example

```
class Animal // implicitly written extends Object
{}
```

On the other hand, if a class has an `extends` clause, then it does not directly inherit from Object. But its parent class inherits from object. As inheritance is transitive, therefore the class also inherits the functions of Object. Example

```
class Dog extends Animal {}

class Animal // implicitly written extends Object
{}
```

This means `Dog` is an `Animal` and `Animal` is an `Object`. Therefore `Dog` is an `Object`. You could write `Object o = (Object) new Dog();` and that would totally be fine.

This can go arbitrarily deep. For example you could now have a class `Poodle` which inherits `Dog` which inherits `Animal` which inherits `Object`. Therefore a `Poodle` is an `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

By using inheritance , a child class will inherit object class through parent class.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is known as - Multilevel inheritance.

Multilevel inheritance refers to a mechanism in OO technology where one can inherit from a derived class, thereby making this derived class the base class for the new class.

i.e. - A is Object class, B is the base class that you want to inherit and C is your child class.

[image]

btw Java 8 has introduced default method to handle basic multiple inheritance problem ( though I don't agree that it solves the actual problem) - [check default methods in Java 8](https://www.programcreek.com/2014/12/default-methods-in-java-8-and-multiple-inheritance/)